# Keep trailing blank in string

Tags: sas, datastep, trailing

I have the following temp dataset with 2 observations.
The second observation contains a trailing blank.In the `data _null_` step I read the value from the second observation with `call symput`.
In the `put` statement the value is written to the log with 6 blanks: `TEXT=Test      controltext`.

How can I achieve that `TEXT=Test controltext` is printed? In temp dataset are some observation with trailing blank and some with none. So I do not know if there is a trailing blank...

```
data temp;
  a="MyTesttext";
  output;
  a="Test ";
  output;
run;

data _null_;
  set temp;
  if _n_ = 2 then do;
    call symput('text',a);
  end;
run;

%put &=text.controltext;
```

Comment: There six trailing blanks after 'Test' in the variable A, because the variable A has a length of 10.  Is your goal to preserve one trailing blank in the value of the macro variable &text?

Comment: Correct, I want to preserve the trailing blank which is written to variable a.

Comment: In another comment you said if there were two trailing blanks, you want to preserve them. In this case there are 6 trailing blanks not one. But you only want to preserve one? If the value assigned to A was "text  " would you want to preserve two blanks? Since A="text " and A="text  " both have six trailing blanks, you can't distinguish between them.

Comment: I want to preserve the blanks given in the string at `temp`.In the above example there is one blank. If there are 2 or more blanks I want to preserve these blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the DATA step language, in a character variable if the length of a value is less than the length of the variable, it is padded with trailing blanks.  When you code `a="Test "` (one trailing blank) or `a="Test   "` (three trailing blanks) and the variable A is defined with a length of $10, they are both stored with six trailing blanks.

So:

```
data _null_;
  length a $10;
  a="Test ";
  call symput('TextOneBlank',a);
  a="Test   ";
  call symput('TextThreeBlanks',a);
run;

%put >>&TextOneBlank<<;
%put >>&TextThreeBlanks<<;
```

returns:

```
75   %put >>&TextOneBlank<<;
>>Test      <<
76
77   %put >>&TextThreeBlanks<<;
>>Test      <<
```

One way to preserve a fixed number of trailing blanks is to add your own delimiter to the text value, so that they are not actually trailing blanks.  For example, you can use a pipe as a delimiter:

```
data _null_;
  length a $10;
  a="|Test |";
  call symput('TextOneBlank',scan(a,1,'|'));
  a="|Test   |";
  call symput('TextThreeBlanks',scan(a,1,'|'));
run;
```

which will return:

```
86   %put >>&TextOneBlank<<;
>>Test <<
87   %put >>&TextThreeBlanks<<;
>>Test   <<
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `put` statement result contains "extra" blanks because, in your first datastep, you implicitely initialize variable `a` with a length of 10 (the length of `"MyTesttext"`).

Once variable `a` of length 10 is assigned the value `"Test "`, that extra trailing blank is essentially lost.
You can observe that by running the following:

```
data _null_;
  a="MyTesttext";
  put '"' a +(-1) '"';
  a="Test ";
  put '"' a +(-1) '"';
run;
```

The result in the log is

```
"MyTesttext"
"Test"
```

The extra blank is gone.

You could achieve the results you describe by using `compbl()`, but that would only be correct in this particular case where you had only one trailing blank.

Comment: Hmm, so I have to specify: If I have 2 trailing blanks I also would like to preserve them. This is with `compbl()` not possible as you already mentioned.

Comment: When outputting in the datastep with `put` another approach is to append something and then strip it off as follows by moving the cursor back 2 characters:
`a=cat("Test   ", '|');` 
`put '"' a +(-2) '"';`